# This XPath expression is not working with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Google Chrome as webdriver.

The <kbd>Sign Up</kbd> button code is:

```html
<button type="submit" class="signupbtn btn_full btn btn-action btn-block btn-lg">
    <span class="ink animate" style="height: 488px; width: 488px; top: -215px; left: -118px;"></span>
    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
    Sign Up
</button>
```

### The error code is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
> unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (681, 658)

### My XPath code for execution is:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='headersignupform']/div[9]/button")).click();
```

However, it is not executing the script and is throwing the above error. As you can see, in the console it is locating the button with my code in the console.

[image]

Comment: This is a known issue with recent versions of Chrome. Make sure that you update Chrome and the Selenium Chrome driver to the newest and try again. You shouldn't need these workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use focus or scroll to that element.
You also might have to use an explicit wait.

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='headersignupform']/div[9]/button"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

If it still does not work, use `JavascriptExecutor`:

```java
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Hello Shubham, 2nd option worked for me. however i am not so sure about that code as why we need to use that, any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: as I told you some time due to element is out of focus and selenium require focus, scroll and wait at time while JavascriptExecutor work directly on the JS so i will work if the locator is fine. please accept the answer if it helps

Answer (score 2):

It seems the <kbd>Sign Up</kbd> button has an overlay. So to interact directly with the <kbd>Sign Up</kbd> button, we need to use the help of *JavascriptExecutor* as follows:

```java
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='signupbtn btn_full btn btn-action btn-block btn-lg']"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

Comment: Hello Debanjan, this code works but could you please kindly explain in bit more detail as why we have to use JavascriptExecutor?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an action class for the same:

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='headersignupform']/div[9]/button"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

The second thing is it's always advisable to use an exact tag instead of *[@id =""].

Comment: Hello Aarya, i tried this but it received the same error. It only works with Javaexecutescript. Thank you for your help.